# Passing dynamic value as parameter to @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring

I need to read property from property file with property name having one dynamic part.
e.g.  **com.sequence.<sequence_name>.suffix**
where **<sequence_name>** is decided at runtime.

How can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading properties file values using @value,Use Autowired Environment in the same class and read the property value from environment.
Example:

```
@Autowired
Environment env;

public void examples(String sequence_name){
 String value=env.getProperty(("com.sequence.").concate(sequence_name).concat(".suffix"));
}
```